# How do I get rid of this extra space below this column when using bootstrap 5?

Tags: css, spacing, bootstrap-5, gutter

I made the changes as you described but when I check to see how it would look on the phone the blue box and the pink box are separated which I want to be together. I have attached a screenshot of how it looks and I want it to look similar to the desktop version.

I am not sure which entity might be causing this issue.

--EDIT--

Just to provide more clarity here is a screenshot of how the container_tag and container_box should look in the mobile screen (365px).
[Should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lAda.png)

[Is looking like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4f8r.png)

```css
.side_feedback{
    background-color: pink;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 180px;
    border-radius: 10%;
    margin-left: 17px;
}
.container_tag{
    background-color: royalblue;
    min-height: 200px;
    max-width: 2rem;
    border: 6px solid royalblue;
    float: left;
}
.tag{
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    position: relative;
    top: 8rem;
}
.container_box{
    background-color: pink;
    min-height: 200px;
    border-left: 6px solid white;
    width: 95%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-4 g-5">
            <div class="order-2 order-sm-1 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-10">
                <div class="col-md">
                    <div class="side_feedback">
                        <p>Give us feedback!</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="order-1 order-sm-2 col-10">
                <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-1 row-cols-md-1 row-cols-lg-1 row-cols-auto g-4">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="container_tag">
                            <h3 class="tag">TEXT</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="container_box">
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="col-12"> 
                        <div class="container_tag">
                            <h3 class="tag">TEXT</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="container_box">
                            
                        </div>    
                    </div> 
                    <div class="col-12"> 
                        <div class="container_tag">
                            <h3 class="tag">TEXT</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="container_box">
                            
                        </div>    
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re referencing the large vertical white space below the two pink blocks, that’s there because you’re using `position: relative` on the pink `container_box.` [`position: relative`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#syntax) positions the element normally (below your `container_tag` div) and then moves the element to the new position — the original space remains.

To get rid of the white space, add `float: left` to the styles for both of your containers.

```css
.container_tag {
    background-color: royalblue;
    min-height: 180px;
    width: 9%;
    max-width: 3.2rem;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.tag {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg)
}

.container_box {
    background-color: pink;
    min-height: 180px;
    border-left: 6px solid white;
    width: 91%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
    .container_box {
        width: calc(100% - 3.2rem);
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-10 px-0">
            <div class="row gx-0">
                <div class="col-12 mb-3">
                    <div class="container_tag">
                        <h3 class="tag">Text</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container_box">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 mb-3">
                    <div class="container_tag">
                        <h3 class="tag">Text</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container_box">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

One other note - you don't need to give the same column class for different breakpoints (col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-xs-10). Just use col-10 and that will apply to all of the following breakpoints. And BS-5 doesn't use `xs` - that was for Bootstrap 3.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I have a quick question. As a result of the suggested changes, the alignment of the text and container box is not responsive anymore. How should I ensure that it looks the same as it does in desktop and mobile versions?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *looks the same as it does in desktop and mobile versions*, but I modified the code to use container-fluid so it will expand to match the display width.

Comment: I have added the screenshot of how the container tag and container box look on a phone. Do you have any suggestions as to how that can be fixed so that the design is responsive?

Comment: I saw your screenshot of what I'm assuming is your current code (which is different from what the code in my answer produces), but it's not clear what you mean by "the design is responsive." Can you use a graphics program (e.g. Photoshop, GIMP, etc.) to illustrate what you want the display to be on a phone (360px wide) versus a tablet (768px wide) or larger?

Comment: I have added another screenshot of how it should look on a phone in comparison to how it looks right now. @Rich DeBourke

Comment: If you want some space between each row, you can add one of the Bootstrap spacing classes (e.g. mb-3) - I've updated the snippet to include a space. *You did provide a phone layout, but the aspect ratio of your layout (672x461) is more for a tablet than a phone, and you did not provide any info for what the layout should look like on a larger display - if the updated snippet isn't what you need, it would be helpful to have more details on what you're trying to create.*